# Multiple groups for field calculator aggregates?

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know if it possible to use multiple groups in the QGIS field calculator?

I have a polygon layer that I want to check that the area calculations are being done correctly. The layer is derived from 3 layers intersected. A paddock polygon is intersected with a 2, 3, 5 and 8km buffer derived from points within the paddock. This intersect is then intersected with a land units layer (soil, vegetation etc).

What I would like to do is to sum the land unit area grouped by the land unit type and the buffered distance eg 8km buffer. But I can't quite figure out how to do it.

I have tried 
`sum("LUAREAKM2", WA_DIST" AND "LAND_UNIT")` which returns zero.

I have also tried to create nested statements but they usually end up invalid.

This is the second time in many weeks that I have tried to figure this out, last week I was trying to calculate some statistics based on multiple groups and ended up resorting to exporting to a spreadsheet and using Excel.

Comment: try `sum("LUAREAKM2", concat("WA_DIST" , "LAND_UNIT"))`